# Organogran in FLEX

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

Need some help I need to mount an organization chart in flex like this that is the link.

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/564046/organogram/lista.html
```

Would anyone know any way to do this?

Comment: Please specify what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are other libraries but can not remember what it was.
I hope you serve, I have not used

[Go to cubecomponents](https://code.google.com/p/cubecomponents/)

In the [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/)

[image]
Regars

Comment: Thank you but the problem with this component is that it is paid

Comment: Yes the second is paid, the first is open source.